# Airpod pros active noise cancellation seems to activate with loud noises normal?

Tags: airpods

Whenever there's a high-pitched screeching noise the active noise cancelation on my airpods pros activates itself for a few seconds. Is this a feature or a bug on my model? Has anyone else ever experienced this and should I return these for an exchange?

Answer (score 1):

I experience this as well - pretty sure it’s a feature to protect our hearing.